# Bind mount file with destination relative to USER's home

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a Dockerfile which specifies a USER and executes a script as that user. The script requires an file mounted in that user's home directory. Assuming I don't know what that user is or what its home directory is (and want to keep it dynamic instead of using `docker inspect` and manually entering it), is it possible to mount a file in the container with the destination being relative to USER's home?

i.e. `docker run -v $PWD/file:somedir/file <image>`

where `$PWD/file` on the host ends up mounted at `~USER/somedir/file` in the container.

This currently gives `docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '$PWD/file:somedir/file': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'somedir/file' mount path must be absolute.`

Comment: You can `grep` home directory of that user in `/etc/passwd` and then automate it via a shell script or commands. Also as error mentioned, path must be absolute, like `/somedir/file`. Have you tried the first one I said? Also what's the user to run? I mean is that you add via `useradd ...` or it's one of pre-existed users?

Comment: @Saeed I know I could use a script etc, I was wondering if there was a tidier way of doing it. The user is made with `useradd` in the Dockerfile then set with `USER` but the user to be made is set by a `ARG` variable.

Comment: What should happen if you `docker push` the image to a registry, and I download and run it on my workstation (as a different user with a different filesystem layout)?

Comment: @David it would be the same situation since the user was specified (and created) in the dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Docker images generally have a fixed filesystem layout.  They don't typically have "multiple users", "home directories", or variable paths, the way you might on a standard server setup.

For the sort of setup you describe, I might suggest:

- Install your application in some easy-to-find directory like `/app`.  (Pick a path; don't have it be an environment variable.)
- Have the application and its files be owned by `root` and not world-writeable.
- Have the image install some non-root user.  It doesn't matter what that user is, and it doesn't need to match any particular host user.
- The application should expect some easy-to-find directory like `/data`.
- When you run the application, specify both the host user ID and the content to mount on `/data`.

```sh
FROM ???
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .            # will be owned by root (and that's okay)
RUN adduser user    # can be any name and any non-0 uid
RUN mkdir /data && chown user /data
ENV DATA_DIR=/data  # to tell the application where it is
USER user
CMD ["/app/the_application"]
```

```sh
sudo docker run --rm \
  -v "$PWD/content":/data \
  -u $(id -u) \
  the-image
```

It's important to keep the application and data separate, so that the bind-mount doesn't overwrite the application data.  You wouldn't usually pass any host-specific data into the build process so that the built image can be reused in different environments.

(If the application is really just a script, it's not a long-running process, and the single important thing it does is manipulate files in the user's home directory, you might find just distributing the script to be much easier than trying to run it via Docker.)

Comment: Thanks, honestly the main thing I was looking for was a yes/no on the relative path bit. but your points are useful to me nonetheless. One question about them: if I wanted part of the script to ssh into another computer, how would you deal with the file permissions etc.? i.e. if an ssh key is mounted in your `/data` dir